# Implementing interface depending on current API

Tags: java, interface

How can I implement an interface only in some cases?

Lets say, we have `int sdkVersion` and only if its higher than `10` the interface `TenPlusInterface` exists.

For code in methods, I could just check it and say:

```
if (sdkVersion > 10) {
    ClassForApiTen cls = new ClassForApiTen();
    ...
}
```

But if my `sdkVersion < 10`, I cannot do a `public class MyClass implements TenPlusInterface`.
So what would be a recommended way to implement the interface only in defined cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a subclass of your class, and have that subclass implement the interface.

```
public class MyClass { ... }

public class TenPlusMyClass extends MyClass implements TenPlusInterface {}

public class MyClassFactory {
     MyClass getMyClass(int sdkVersion) { 
        return sdkVersion > 10 ? new TenPlusMyClass() : new MyClass();
     }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! (And I learned sth about protected prefix, I never used before on that way ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class. And based on the condition I.e.>10 or <10 you can write anonymous the inner class.